# Remove curly brackets at the end of values in column of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
Agent   Info
A       {"id": 0, "value": 235, "hours": 40} {}
B       {"id": 1, "value": 771, "hours": 64} {}
C       HttpResponse(202 Accepted,List(Server: SAP Application) {}
```

As you see at the end of each value in column Info there are space and curly brackets {}. How to get rid of them from my dataframe? I don't really get what kind of regex to write here

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to remove the curly brackets at the end you do not even need regex:

**Code:**

```
df[, 2] <- sapply(df[, 2], function(a){
  unlist(strsplit(a, " {}", fixed = T))[1]
  })

#  c.1..2..3.                                              c.a..b..c.
#1          1                    {'id': 0, 'value': 235, 'hours': 40}
#2          2                    {'id': 1, 'value': 771, 'hours': 64}
#3          3 HttpResponse(202 Accepted,List(Server: SAP Application)
```

**Data:**

```
a <- "{'id': 0, 'value': 235, 'hours': 40} {}"
b <- "{'id': 1, 'value': 771, 'hours': 64} {}"
c <- "HttpResponse(202 Accepted,List(Server: SAP Application) {}"
df <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3), c(a, b, c))

#  c.1..2..3.                                                 c.a..b..c.
#1          1                    {'id': 0, 'value': 235, 'hours': 40} {}
#2          2                    {'id': 1, 'value': 771, 'hours': 64} {}
#3          3 HttpResponse(202 Accepted,List(Server: SAP Application) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sub`, you can do :

```
df$Info <- sub('\\s\\{\\}$', '', df$Info)
df
#  Agent                                                    Info
#1     A                          {id: 0, value: 235, hours: 40}
#2     B                          {id: 1, value: 771, hours: 64}
#3     C HttpResponse(202 Accepted,List(Server: SAP Application)
```